# What is the best model for predicting delays?

Tags: classification, linear-regression, forecasting

Supposing we need to predict delays based on a previous dataset that contains the history of several, lets say, providers and their delivery delays. The goal is to minimize the loss due to those delays. Classification model could identify the "good" and "bad" providers but multiple regression may forecast the delays of each one with some degree of confidence. What should we use for that kind of issue ?

Comment: Time series analysis might be the answer

Comment: Regression based on provider features and provider (average) delay as output. Is an option

Comment: Time series ?!? Interesting. I think I need to know more about possible applications of time series.